# How to have a function return one of two iterators with same item type?

Tags: rust, iterator

The [following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=958ceee4235220663216b295de6f6bb8) does not compile because the two iterators have different signatures. But, both iterators return the same item type and conceptually behave the same.

```rust
fn f(flag: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> {
    if flag {
        (0..8).into_iter()
    } else {
        (0..8).into_iter().map(|x| x + 1)
    }
}
```

I want to write a function that returns items generated from different variants of an algorithm, selected by values I pass into the function. How can I achieve this?

Ultimately, I need to use this in a `no_std` environment. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in way of doing this, but implementing something that works is not overly tricky.

What you need is a type that can represent both the result of `(0..8).into_iter()` - which is one kind of `Iterator<Item=u8>` and also `(0..8).into_iter().map(|x| x+1)`. The typical choice for this if you don't want to use Boxed traits, is to create an enum with two options.

Then if you implement `Iterator<Item=u8>` on your enum and you're done.

Such an enum might look like:

```
pub enum EitherIter<AIterType, BIterType> {
    A(AIterType),
    B(BIterType),
}

impl<AIterType, BIterType> Iterator for EitherIter<AIterType, BIterType>
where
    AIterType: Iterator,
    BIterType: Iterator<Item = AIterType::Item>,
{
    type Item = AIterType::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<<Self as Iterator>::Item> {
        match self {
            EitherIter::A(it) => it.next(),
            EitherIter::B(it) => it.next(),
        }
    }
}
```

Then using it you wrap each return type in one of the types.

```
pub fn f(flag: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> {
    if flag {
        EitherIter::A((0..8).into_iter())
    } else {
        EitherIter::B((0..8).into_iter().map(|x| x + 1))
    }
}
```

You can try this out in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9369fd10aba2f264aed002a17446ad2e).

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/either provides this enum already written.

Comment: @KevinReid that's really neat. I'd seen `either` before but wasn't aware that it implemented the `Iterator` trait. I guess one advantage of this is that you can trivially extend it to more than two cases by adding another enum member.

Comment: Or [`itertools::Either`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.3/itertools/enum.Either.html) offers the same functionality if you already have `itertools`.

Comment: In fact, it looks like `itertools::Either` and `either::Either` are **identical**. (The example code in the function documentation for all the functions I looked at are identical - which  would be more than a convention in function naming)

Comment: Yep, there we go. In the `itertools::lib.rs` we have `pub use either::Either;` and in its `Cargo.toml` we have `either = { version = "1.0", default-features = false }`. So it uses and exports a slightly older version of `either` (current is 1.6 I think)